# iOS app crashes when tries to add child viewcontroller with mapView inside

Tags: swift, mapkit, childviewcontroller

I have tabbarController where i put parent viewController with container view inside.

```
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    viewControllers = [
         ParentViewController()
    ]
}
```

On init i'm initializing 2 child view controllers and adding 1st controller (that does't contain MapView) as child viewController.
At some point of time i need to switch between child controllers, and in that point app crashes

```
public class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView! 

    let firstChildController: ViewControllerWithoutMapView
    let secondChildController: ViewControllerWithMapView

    init() {
        firstChildController = ViewControllerWithoutMapView()
        secondChildController = ViewControllerWithMapView()
        super.init(nibName: "ParentViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        firstChildController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        addChildViewController(firstChildController)
        firstChildController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
        containerView.addSubview(firstChildController.view)
        firstChildController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    func switchChildControllers() {
        secondChildController.view.frame = containerView.bounds <<<<< crash here
        .....
    }
}
```

I know about crashes that appears if you're not importing MapKit, i tried to import it everywhere - no luck.

What is the correct way to switch child viewControllers with MapView inside one of it?

Comment: Where does the stacktrace say the crash occurred?

Comment: @JAL it doesn't show any stacktrace - it points to line that crashes and shows BAD_ACCESS. Who knows, maybe that's because i'm using Carthage.

Comment: at least you should be able to break at the crash and print out the stack strace?

Comment: usually containerView is nil or the vc is nil and cause crash. but you can only know when you get the back trace

Comment: your `containerView` may be`nil` after `didMoveToParentViewController`